# Is there a way to send data between activities without using intent?

Tags: android

I have a username unique to every user that I want to send to a certain activity, but I don't want to use intents:

```java
    //create an intent and sends username
     Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterOwner.this, Owner.class);
     intent.putExtra("USERNAME",usernam);
     startActivity(intent);
```

I want to send data to an activity without going to that activity, `startActivity(intent);` makes me go to the activity; I don't want that.

I just want to send data without starting the other activity.

Comment: Can you make the question more clear? You want to send the username to Owner activity. But without starting it?

Comment: yes ,i want to send the variable username to Owner activity without starting owner activity ,is it possible ?@GeorgeArokiam

Comment: If you don't start an activity then that activity doesn't exist. But I guess I understand your problem. Let me attempt to answer it

Comment: the activity will start but i don't want it to start right after i send the username ,there is another activity before it i want to start (but i don't want to keep passing the username till i reach that activity) @GeorgeArokiam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to have a particular data available between activities. One of the methods to achieve this is by making use of the SharedPreferences.

From your first activity(RegisterOwner)

```
SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFERENCENAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("USERNAME",usernam);
editor.apply();
```

Once you do this the username is stored in the shared preferences. Now you have this data available throughout your app.

So from the Owner activity you can retrieve this as follows:

```
SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFERENCENAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = mySharedPreferences.getString("USERNAME", "");
```

Comment: I have 2 questions , first: if i used "putString("USERNAME",usernam);" , then i used it again ,will it over write the older value ? , second: in "getString("USERNAME", "");" , why there are empty quotes as the 2nd param ? , Thanks.

Comment: Yes if you call putString twice the second value will overwrite the first one. The empty quotes is the default value. i.e. in case you never assigned any value to  "USERNAME" what would you like the getString to return. You can add any default value that you want. ex. String username = mySharedPreferences.getString("USERNAME", "NEVER_ASSIGNED_ANYTHING");