# how to sent data of edit text to other activity by using method

Tags: android

i am trying to get the value of edit text from  method in register activity and calling that method from  Other Activity but its always  get null value i am not willing to use intent

Comment: post your method and some more detail of workflow

Comment: Why are you "not willing to" use intent to pass data between activities even if Intents are meant to be used that way? Why do you want to overcomplicate stuff? If you have any special reason to use anything other than Intent, please add it in your question.

Comment: if i used intent to pass data then i have to passed that data  to  several   activity  and there may a chance of user that he skip that particular activity in which i am using intent to pass data  in  that case it will give null value,i hope u understand

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you are not willing to use intent to move values between activities.
You can do it by using SharedPreferences as mentioned here [Is there a way to send data between activities without using intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794224/9233991)
But this isn't what SharedPreferences are meant for
Here is a link to the [SharedPreferences Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Comment: if i used intent to pass data then i have to passed that data to several activity and there may a chance of user that he skip that particular activity in which i am using intent to pass data in that case it will give null value.

Comment: User cant just jump activities...it can only move between activities when you create an intent for him(or when he press the back button which you should handle in your code) and when you create the intent just use putExtra to pass the values...
or you can use  SharedPreferences as i mentioned before